# Anaconda Python Modules in Standard Python 3.5

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I'm pretty new to programming, and am generally unfamiliar with how stuff like environments and distributions work.

I found myself needing to use a module in the SciPy library for python, and when the standard *pip install* failed, I got to googling and found that the recommended way to access these modules is to install an entirely new python distribution called Anaconda with it's own more advanced spyder IDE, more included libraries, etc.

I'm not averse to learning the new IDE, but my question is that if I want to continue using the simple and fast IDLE IDE for making scripts that make use of the SciPy modules, is there any way to get my existing Python35 installation recognize the included Anaconda modules? Or do I have to use Anaconda for all of my future programming now?

Note: I was able to get scipy seperately via http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy, but I'm still interested in using the other included anaconda modules.

My apologies if this is an inappropriate question or if it has been answered before, I searched to the best of my abilities but didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Are you saying you did install Anaconda, and you want your other Python to recognize the modules Anaconda installed?  Or are you saying you want to install other modules that Anaconda would install, but without installing Anaconda?

Comment: I did install Anaconda, and was wondering if it is possible to get the standard python to recognize the anaconda modules.

Comment: Check this link:https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration You should consider using Spyder: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/Dr8xFdKbA20

Comment: Thanks for the input! Much appreciated. I'll give those a look.